# How to fix 'Argument of type 'Data' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit(data: Referentiel) {
    this.route.data
        .filter(data => !isNil(data) && !isEmpty(data))
        .takeWhile(() => this.alive).subscribe(data => {
            this.profilConnecte = data['utilisateur'].profil;
        });
}
```

And data produces the following [ts] error in third line (!isNil(data) && !isEmpty(data)):

`[ts] Argument of type 'Data' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

I think I have to set this Argument, but I tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: you should check what is type of `data['utilisateur'].profil`

Comment: @porgo is type any, but I think is not here the problem...

Comment: this error says that you are trying to assign variable of type `Data` to variable of type `string`. So I assume that error is caused by line: `this.profilConnecte = data['utilisateur'].profil;` You should check types of this variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this error by imports alias **isNil** and **isEmpty**.

```
import isNil from 'lodash-es/isNil';
import isEmpty from 'lodash-es/isEmpty';
```

Then, data is recognized.

I hope you'll find it interesting.